# File occupied by other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wrote this static log class to record all status during many threads. Sometimes I got a exception saying the log file(that the program is writing) was occupied. It seems other thread was writing the file at the same time. I made all this works invoke to UI thread to avoid this exception, but it still happens. Any suggestion? Thanks.

BTW, I know I may use lock(mLog) to avoid this problem, but I am still wondering why this happens, UI thread should never run 2 Log.UpdateLog functions at the same time, am I right?

```
public partial class LogForm : Form
{
    private StringBuilder mLog;

    public LogForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mLog = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void Write(string msg, bool save)
    {
        mLog.Insert(0, msg + "\r\n\r\n" + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n\r\n");

        if (save)
        {
            SaveFile();
        }
    }

    private void SaveFile()
    {
        FileStream file;
        file = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + @"\LOG.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
        sw.Write(mLog.ToString());
        sw.Close();
        file.Close();
    }


}

public static class Log
{
    private delegate void mUIInvoke(string msg, bool save);

    private static LogForm mLogForm = new LogForm();

    public static void Write(string msg, bool save)
    {
        msg += "\r\nTIME:" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

        if (mLogForm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            mUIInvoke invoke = new mUIInvoke(UpdateLog);
            mLogForm.BeginInvoke(invoke, new object[] { msg, save });
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateLog(msg, save);
        }
    }


    private static void UpdateLog(string msg, bool save)
    {
        mLogForm.Write(msg, save);
    }

}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to look into pre-existing logging frameworks, such as `NLog`. Other than that, I don't see anywhere any indication where you're getting an exception.

Comment: You'll need to put locks around your functions in LogForm

Comment: Hi Kyle, I know I could use locks, but I dont understand why this happen. I thought that invoking to UI thread should be OK

Comment: It is not a problem of the UI thread. The problem is (mainly) in the SaveFile method. If two different threads try to access this method one could find the file still in use by the other thread. A simple lock could resolve the problem

Comment: Hi Steve, The SaveFile method is only called from Log.Write method, in Log.Write, I makes them to the UI Thread, which means all Write works should be Asynchronous

Comment: Hi everyone
I figured out this problem with one of my friends.
Its actually because the mLogForm has never been showed before mLogForm.InvokeRequired is called. If its not showed, there will NEVER be a handle for mLogForm. Without handle, you will not be able to call mLogForm.InvokeRequired in its right way.
Which means it will return false even if other thread calls Log.Write
and then I got a lot threads running UpdateLog method, caused this problem.
To make sure you could use invoke to a unshowed form, use CreateHandle() while you create this form.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not an elegant method for implementing logging as you've multiple threads in your class. If you want a better design, your logging stuffs has to be moved out from form class as logging is something independent and threads shouldn't access a "form" to "log" make it meaningful.

There are two alternatives for this.

1. Go for logging frameworks which are tested and proven like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)
2. Make this logging class independant and create an instance (mostly a singleton though I am against singleton classes) of logger class and share it between multiple threads. file management, logging functions etc. has to be managed separately. All the operations has to be protected with thread synchronization mechanisms like mutex. There are several ways to implement a logging framework. It's all depends on how much of you really need!

Unless it's not a big deal or for learning purpose, I would suggest you to use existing logging frameworks, especially when using with production quality code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of the UI thread. The problem is (mainly) in the SaveFile method. If two different threads try to access this method one could find the file still in use by the other thread. A simple lock could resolve the problem.

So immagine Thread A that call `mLogForm.Write`
It enters the method and reach without interruption the SaveFile method,
it open the file stream but at this point is interrupted and the OS decides to run Thread B
Thread B runs and reach the same SaveFile finding the File locked by the previous thread suspended

Comment: The SaveFile method is only called from Log.Write method, in Log.Write, I makes them to the UI Thread, which means all Write works should be Asynchronous.
see Log.Write method.  
So if a thread calls mLogForm.Write, it should be UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a theory: your logging form is accessed through static variable. This variable is initialized on first access of the Log class, and this first access can happen from non-ui thread. So your form could be created on a non-ui thread, and this could cause the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: so mLogForm.Invoke will not get my UpdateLog method to UI thread? you mean if I create a Form from a non-ui thread, this Form will not on the UI thread?
still confused. As you said, if the mLogForm is not on UI thread, lets say mLogForm is on Thread A. I used mLogForm.Invoke to get all UpdateLog method to Thread A. Then it still should be safe because there is NO Thread B that will call UpdateLog method

Comment: I haven't found an easy confirmation for this, but you can have an experiment yourself - call Log.Write first thing in your application, before stating threads, so that form will be created on ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this problem with one of my friends.
Its actually because the mLogForm has never been showed before mLogForm.InvokeRequired is called. If its not showed, there will NEVER be a handle for mLogForm. Without handle, you will not be able to call mLogForm.InvokeRequired in its right way.
Which means it will return false even if other thread calls Log.Write
and then I got a lot threads running UpdateLog method, caused this problem.
To make sure you could use invoke to a unshowed form, use CreateHandle() while you create this form.
Thanks.